# Can I have table variable in stored procedure in redshift?

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, amazon-redshift, table-variable

We are planning to create a procedure for our logic what should be in PL SQL in redshift (using workbench).
Can we use a table variable to traverse through the rows of the table ? Like we have dataframe in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Sort of. Redshift implements a `RECORD` data type for stored procedures. Variables with this type can hold an arbitrary sets of rows.

- ["Overview of stored procedures in Amazon Redshift" > "Record types"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-structure.html#r_PLpgSQL-record-type)

However, note that you cannot currently `SELECT` from a `RECORD` typed variable, only loop over the content.

There are several examples of using a `RECORD` variable in our GitHub repository: ["amazon-redshift-utils/src/StoredProcedures/"](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/tree/master/src/StoredProcedures)

Comment: Thanks. I would try to look more into RECORD. But the problem is, nothing I do is helping me to print anything, I have tried - RAISE INFO 'info' , dbms output, print and RAISE EXCEPTIONS. It says syntax error everytime.

Comment: The syntax can be quite different compared to other DBs. Recommend starting with the simplest possible SP that does nothing but `RAISE INFO` and then iterate from there.